# How to exclude a column during fitering in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JavaScript (jquery) to filter output of my query. But wen try to filter output table, filter finds hidden column values.
I need to exclude this hidden column during filtering.
Here is the code:

```
var $rowsActiveUser = $('#ku_list tr');
$('#search_ku').keyup(function() {
 var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
  $rowsActiveUser.show().filter(function() {
  var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
   return !~text.indexOf(val);
 }).hide();
});
```

and fiddle is here [fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/tceydeliler/426mqc1a/)

If you filter "9c" u will see 2 output. One of is in hidden column, other is in MAC address column. I want to exclue hidden one in my filter process. How can I modify my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a clone of the column so as not to affect the actual elements, then remove the hidden rows from the clone before you get the text you compare against

```
$rowsActiveUser.show().filter(function() {
    var clone = $(this).clone();
    clone.find('td.hidden').remove()
    var text = clone.text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    return !~text.indexOf(val);
}).hide();
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/426mqc1a/2/)

Comment: Only to filtering, yes it can works. But, I have to preserve hidden value there. Because I need this value to modify that rows. Such as delete user connection by using enry id criteria.

Comment: The value is still there, it's not removed in any way from the original HTML ?

Comment: Ok. I tested it in my real env. It works perfectly. Thanks for your assistances. Regards...